# How to add data into SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to add a movie to a database along with the filename and date released, all of which are supposed to be strings. I'm also trying to print the list of objects in the database to the TextView called movieList. When I attempt to add to the database I'm getting an error on "db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS,null,values);" in MyDBHandler.java and in MainActivity.java I'm getting an error on "dbHandler.addMovie(movie)" any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button thebutton=findViewById(R.id.serviceButton);
        movieInput=findViewById(R.id.movieInput);
        movieList=findViewById(R.id.movieList);
        dbHandler=new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
        dateReleased=findViewById(R.id.dateReleasedTxt);
        final Button addButton=findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        final Button deleteButton=findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        printDatabase();


        thebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                startService(Intent1);
               //Intent theIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,theIntentService.class);
               //startService(theIntent);
            }
        });
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fileName="/sdcard/.mpg";
                Movies movie=new Movies(movieInput.getText().toString(),dateReleased.getText().toString(),fileName);
                //will only accept a movie object
                dbHandler.addMovie(movie);
                printDatabase();
            }

        });
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputText=movieList.getText().toString();
                dbHandler.deleteMovie(inputText);
            }
        });


    }

    public void printDatabase()
    {
        String dbString=dbHandler.databaseToString();
        movieList.setText(dbString);
        movieInput.setText("");
    }
```

below is MyDBHandler.java

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="movies.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS="_movies";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE="_title";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATERELEASED="_dateReleased";
    public static final String COLUMN_FILENAME="_fileName";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //INFORMATION ABOUT EACH COLUMN FOR THE TABLE
        String query="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+"("+
                COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_DATERELEASED+"TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_FILENAME+" TEXT "
                +" ); ";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add a new row to the database
    public void addMovie(Movies movie)
    {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE,movie.get_name());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATERELEASED,movie.get_dateReleased());
        values.put(COLUMN_FILENAME,movie.get_fileName());
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
```

Here's the error

```
2018-10-18 20:05:12.208 9852-9852/com.example.bryce.purnellassignment_5 E/SQLiteLog: (1) table _movies has no column named _dateReleased
2018-10-18 20:05:12.209 9852-9852/com.example.bryce.purnellassignment_5 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting _dateReleased=Date Released _title= _fileName=/sdcard/.mpg
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table _movies has no column named _dateReleased (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO _movies(_dateReleased,_title,_fileName) VALUES (?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
        at com.example.bryce.purnellassignment_5.MyDBHandler.addMovie(MyDBHandler.java:47)
        at com.example.bryce.purnellassignment_5.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: can you show me the full error?

Comment: @jayshah just added it. thanks

Comment: My guess is that your `CREATE TABLE` statement is not being run, or at least the one in your `onCreate()` method is not being run.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
COLUMN_DATERELEASED+"TEXT, "
```

to

```
COLUMN_DATERELEASED+" TEXT, "
```

on MyDBHandler.java method onCreate

Comment: now it doesn't crash, but it doesn't print to the view

Comment: well, it's query for insert to table, right? are you already check your data is inserted to table? and if you want get data from database you must do select query. sorry if my english bad :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's being added to the database because when i put a log in the printDatabase method I'm not able to print dbString

Comment: create method on MyDBHandler.java and add this code inside it:

**SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, YOUR_TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();
        return numRows;**

and call it on your main activity. it's function is to count how many rows on your table. if you before insert one data, it will result 1

Comment: he will need to do app uninstall and install it again as there are changes in db sturcture.

Comment: unfortunately, yes. sorry, I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table _movies has no column named _dateReleased
```

your query must be spelt wrong.

Answer (score 0):

please try this just paste this line in onCreate

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
  {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
        + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_DATERELEASED + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
        + COLUMN_FILENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(query);
 }
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it, but it won't print on main page

Comment: Maybe try to check out some tutorials on how to retrieve data from an SQLite Database in Android and rewrite your printDatabase() method. (e.g. check [Android Developers | Read information from a database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#ReadDbRow))

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //INFORMATION ABOUT EACH COLUMN FOR THE TABLE
    String query="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+"("+
            COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT, "+
            COLUMN_DATERELEASED+" TEXT, "+
            COLUMN_FILENAME+" TEXT "
            +" ); ";
    db.execSQL(query);
```

Error was there in the COLUMN_DATERELEASED+" TEXT, "  Keep space just after " and before specify the data type .